# Server-side processing of DataTables in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, datatables, server-side

I have a spring boot app with Rest api and Oracle database and react front. It works well, but now I want to try datatables with server side processing. I have quite a lot of entities and controllers. I would like to clarify something. Every example I used to learn used jpa. Is it possible to use JDBC? (I have JDBC set up and I don't want to redo all in jpa). When I tried to change examples to jdbc they usually respond with null pointer exception. Also, how about the controller? I saw examples using both get and post. Usually I use get to get the data. But from what I tried to replicate and use with my database, post seems to be recognized, and Get throws the null. Do I need to specify the draw and other paramenters in body or where? Also, is there maybe only one controller which can somehow prepare the response from others or i should change every single controller? Sorry, it's my first time with datatables server-side.
This is what I use, is it enough?

```
componentDidMount() {
        var index = null;
        var table = $(this.refs.main).DataTable({
            dom: '<"data-table-wrapper"t>',
            data: this.props.data,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "pageLength": 1,
            "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( {
                "url": "/api/calculations",
                "type": "POS"
                "data": function (data) {
                    return data = JSON.stringify(data);
             }}),
             'pagingType':   'simple',
             'order':        [[0,'asc']],
             'pageLength': 100,
             "columns": this.props.columns
        });
        $(this.refs.main).on('click', 'tr', () => {
            var index = table.row(this).index();
            var item = table.row(this).data();
            this.updateIndex(index);
            console.log(index);
            console.log(item);
        });
    }
```

So, my frontend, after authenticating and authorizating, goes to that component, where I perform (there was pagination in api, i just decided to try without it now)

```
  fetchItems = async (page, elements) => {
    try {
      const response = await CalculationsApiService.fetchAll()
      this.setState({ items: response.data })
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({
        e,
        isError: true,
        items: null,
      })
    }
  }
```

And later in render I Call my child component with my universal table and pass the columns and items as props (the first portion of code in this post) Maybe the error is that I call for data first in parent and then ajax in child? What about the controllers in general? Can I use normal rest controllers somehow and just send something special from my react? When not modified by the tutorial above i have a normal rest api with responseentity

Comment: Are you using Spring-Data? Can you show the Java code and the payload sent from the frontend rather than the request code?

Comment: Will edit now! Thanks

Comment: I just don't understand, will my normal rest api work? Or do i need to modify every controller heavily? and some tutorials use a special set of classes lile PaginationCriteria and some seem not to.. I just can't understand what I'm supposed to use

Comment: Forget all the advanced terminology. You're sending JSON to an API endpoint that lives server-side. What data you really send will end up at the other end. Whatever you choose to do with it there, is up to your use case, but it'll be JSON, not a DataTable